# Sounds play for about 30 times then stop

Tags: android, react-native

I am using the [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/i) module and I can play a sound for about 30 times. Doesn't matter if it is Sound1 for 30 times or multiple sounds. But after those 30 times it stops.

Reloading doesn't fix it, closing the app by swiping it away does.

How do I fix this problem?

This is how I use the sounds:

```
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';


render() {
  let buttonClickSound = new Sound('button.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE);

  _onClick = () => {
   buttonClickSound.play()
  }
}
```

Can't imagine there is something wrong there the sounds work perfectly.

Comment: does it stop really after 30 times (or sometimes 31 or 28 )? Maybe it stops because your app is stopped....

Comment: It stops after 31 times. No other sounds play while I can still use the app. When I reload the app the sounds still don't work. I have to close the app process totally to fix it. Then I can play another 31 sounds and it happens again.

Comment: I counted again and it seems like it's always 31 sounds. AFTER 31 it doesn't play any sounds anymore even if it is another file.

Comment: how have you done the playing sound again and again? Have you used `setNumberOfLoops(-1);` for an infinite loop?

Comment: there are some bug reports on that library that let me guess that it is playing, but the volume is zero. Maybe it´s a bug: https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Comment: Not really. For example I have button click sounds on the homepage, on another page I have a voice saying "Hey" one time for example. I create an instance for every sound and just play it when I need it. After the count of 31 sounds (all sound `play()`s combined) it just stops and doesn't play another sound.

Comment: I could try setting volume back to max in every constructor.. But why would it turn down the volume after a couple times?

Comment: Is there perhaps a better sound module that you would recommend if you don't know how to fix it?

Comment: that depends on your needs which lib you choose. Maybe this link helps to find another one:https://anadea.info/blog/tools-for-audio-processing-in-android-development

Comment: Looking at this link I'm thinking it's because I create too many instances: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509397/mediaplayer-stop-sound-after-30-click

Answer (score 0):

The problem was happening because I was creating too many instances. To solve this I put my music library in the `Redux store`.

So all I had to do was put it in the initial state of my reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

const initialState = {
  backgroundMusic: false,
  buttonClick: new Sound('button.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE),
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.TOGGLE_BACKGROUND_MUSIC:
      return {
        ...state,
        backgroundMusic: !state.backgroundMusic
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```